# Lion Fullscreen Desktop Switching Quirk

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, fullscreen

I make Java programs, many of which require input from the command line before they actually open a window. When I'm using the Terminal in fullscreen mode and I run `java Program`, it jumps over to an open desktop and then does nothing, causing me to have to switch back to the Terminal to do the stuff it's asking and then switch over. I know it's a really simple fix of not using fullscreen but is there any way to let the focus stay on the command line until the program is ready to open the window?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832252/how-is-gui-code-being-invoked-before-my-scanner) at Stack Overflow for the programming-related section of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832252/how-is-gui-code-being-invoked-before-my-scanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not allocating any GUI elements until after the command line input is finished.

If you run your app from a non-fullscreen Terminal, you'll probably notice that the app launches in the Dock (even if no windows appear) before you finish entering your command line stuff. This is probably what's causing the Space-switch.

Comment: Yeah I don't run the constructor until the command line input is finished but it still opens the app in the dock and switches spaces.

Comment: What constructor don't you run? If it's opening in the Dock, then `new Frame()` or `new Dialog()` or some such is being called; if not by you, then by some other code you call.

Comment: Well I THINK it's a JFrame constructor.... I'm using a third party library. I haven't noticed if the issue occurs when I make my own GUI's, I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: Even with regular JFrame constructors it opens in the dock before getting input.

Comment: Is there any way you can get your input before calling the other code?

Comment: Yeah I could get it from a GUI in some way, but with some homeworks and things like that we're kind of required to use a Scanner. This isn't a huge deal or anything I was just wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant get your input from the command line before calling whatever code launches the Dock icon.

Comment: Not that I know of... when I run the program the first thing that gets run is the `main(String[]args)` method. The first thing I'm doing there is running my Scanner but that's too late... I don't know of any way to get code to run before the main method...

Comment: The class's static initializer is run before main(). As this is now a programming question ("How is GUI code being invoked before my Scanner?"), you should ask on Stack Overflow and link to this question for background. If you find resolution there, you can accept my answer as helpful.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR: I've elaborated [nearby](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45355/20589), but I urge you to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer.

Answer (score 0):

@CajunLuke is right, Apple's Java Virtual Machine prepares the desktop to display a peer component, even before `setVisible()` launches the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). It's a feature, most of the time. One way to achieve the desired effect is to launch the GUI component in a *separate* JVM, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832473/230513) using `ProcessBuilder`.

See also [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/).